# Error occured [Error: Unable to locate the ionic.project file. Are you in your project directory?]

Tags: ionic-framework

For some reason the following error keeps on appearing, after using Ionic start:

```
    Error occured [Error: Unable to locate the ionic.project file. 
    Are you in your project directory?]




    Unable to locate the ionic.project file. 
    Are you in your project directory? (CLI v1.6.5)

    Your system information:

    Cordova CLI: 5.1.1
    Gulp version:  CLI version 3.9.0
    Gulp local:
    Ionic CLI Version: 1.6.5
    Ionic App Lib Version: 0.3.9
    ios-deploy version: Not installed
    ios-sim version: Not installed
    OS: Mac OS X Yosemite
    Node Version: v0.12.4
```

I am in the directory where I called ionic start

Comment: are you sure you are in that directory? Where you are, do you see the  `ionic.project` file?

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your ionic CLI. Worked for me:

```
npm update -g ionic
```